# Roots of $\,ax^2+bx+c\,$ are irrational if $a,b,c$ are odd integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would I show the following.

For all odd integers a,b, and c if z is a solution of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ the z is not rational.

How would I show this? This is what I did

Let a be an odd integer then for a integer k it has the form $a=2k+1$

then $b=2t+1$ for if c integer.

then $c=2r+1$ if s is an integer then I do

$(2k+1)(x)^2+2t+1(x)+(2r+1)=0$

But I find my self stuck on what to do any hint are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: set up $x=m/n$, $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and look modulo $2$. You'll get $$am^2+bn+cn^2\equiv0\pmod2.$$ We have three cases on the parity of the terms. What happens?

---

It is particularly easy to do it for integer roots. Suppose $ax^2+bx+c=0$. If $x$ is even, then $ax^2+bx+c=x(ax+b)+c$ is odd, so it can't be zero. Similarly, if $x$ is odd, then we have the sum of three odd numbers, which is again odd. You can adapt this approach for rationals, as stated above.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Show that the discriminant is not a perfect square. Note that $b^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, and $4ac\equiv 4\pmod{8}$, and therefore $b^2-4ac\equiv 5\pmod{8}$.

**Another way:** If there are rational roots, then the quadratic factors as $(px+q)(rx+s)$, where $p,q, r, s$ are integers. Because of the oddness of $a$ and $c$, $p,q,r,s$ are all odd. But then the coefficient of $x$ in the product is even.

Comment: I see it is not rational because the discriminant is not a perfect square then when you divide it by 2 in the quadratic

Comment: If we use the quadratic formula, the roots are $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{D}}{2a}$. If this is rational, then $\sqrt{}$ is rational. But it isn't. Note the alternate approach that uses less machinery, though it too leaves detail to be filled in.

Comment: I see i think I get the alternative way I see now that because a and c are odds the factors are odd but I a not sure is the coefficient of x in the product 0?

Comment: The coefficient of $x$ is $ps+qr$. Since $ps$ and $qr$ are odd, their sum is even. I prefer the version of the parity argument given by Ian Mateus.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the contrapositive yet?

> If both roots are rational, then at least one of $a$, $b$, or $c$ are even.

Or equivalently, for example,

> If both roots are rational and $a$ and $c$ are odd, then $b$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

If $\rm\ z = m/n\,$  in lowest terms,   [Rational Root Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) $\rm\,\Rightarrow m\mid c,\ n\mid a,\ $ so $\rm\,\ c,a\,\ odd\Rightarrow m,n\,\ odd,$

hence $\rm\,\ \color{#c00}0 = n^2 (a z^2\! + b z + c) = a m^2\! + b mn + c n^2 = odd + odd + odd = \color{#c00}{odd}\ \Rightarrow\Leftarrow\ $  **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ The idea of using *parity* to exclude the existence of roots generalizes, namely

**Parity Root Test** $\ $ A polynomial $\rm\:P(x)\:$ with integer coefficients 
has no integer roots when its constant coefficient and coefficient sum are both odd.

**Proof** $\ $ The test  verifies that $\rm\  P(0) \equiv  1\equiv P(1)\ \ (mod\ 2),\ $ i.e. 
that $\rm\:P(x)\:$ has no roots modulo $2$, hence no integer roots. $\ $ **QED**

The Parity Root Test generalizes to any [ring with a sense of parity,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26843/242) e.g. the Gaussian integers $\rm\: a + b\,{\it i}\ $ for integers $\rm\:a,b.\:$ For much further discussion see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15670/242) and also these [related posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+%22parity+root+test%22)