# If at least one solution $r_1, r_2$ to $ax^2 + bx +c$ is rational, then prove that at least one of $a, b, c$ must be even

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If at least one solution $r_1, r_2$ to $ax^2 + bx +c$ is rational, then prove that at least one of $a, b, c$ must be even.
I have been trying to prove the contrapositive but have been facing trouble. Can anyone help me?

Comment: $(x+1)(x+\pi)=x^2 + (1+\pi)x + \pi$?

Comment: Do you want $a$, $b$, $c\in\Bbb Z$? Recall that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible modulo $2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That's the most reasonable assumption imo.

Comment: $a, b,c $ are integers

Comment: The quadratic equation is that $r_1, r_2 = \frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.  And that number is rational if and only if $b^2 - 4ac$ is a perfect square.  So prove if $b^2 -4ac$ is a perfect square then one of $a,b,c$ is even.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Roots of $\,ax^2+bx+c\,$ are irrational if $a,b,c$ are odd integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597405/roots-of-ax2bxc-are-irrational-if-a-b-c-are-odd-integers)

Answer (score 2):

Using the quadratic formula, you get

$$r_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Since $a,b,c$ are integers, for $r_1$ or $r_2$ to be rational requires the discriminant to be a perfect square, i.e., there's an integer $d$ such that

$$b^2 - 4ac = d^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

If $a,b,c$ are all odd integers, then $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ and $4ac \equiv 4 \pmod 8$, so $d^2 = b^2 - 4ac \equiv 1 - 4 \equiv 5 \pmod 8$, but squares only have congruences of $0,1,4$ modulo $8$. Thus, the assumption must be false, i.e., at least one of $a,b,c$ is even.

Comment: can you explain what the mod and triple equal signs mean

Comment: @RyanTong As explained in the [Definition of congruence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Definition_of_congruence_relation) section of Wikipedia's "Modular arithmetic" article, $a \equiv b \pmod n$ means $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$. As such, for some integer $k$, you have $a = kn + b$. For example, in my first case of using modulos, I wrote if $b$ is odd, then $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$. This is because $1^2 = 1$, $3^2 = 9 = 8 + 1$, $5^2 = 25 = 3\times 8 + 1$, etc. Also, $4ac \equiv 4 \pmod 8$ as odd mult. of $4$ have rem. $4$ when div. by $8$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are integers, then for $ax^2+bx+c$ to have a rational root,
the polynomial must factor:
$$ax^2+bx+c=(rx+t)(ux+v)$$
where $r,\ldots,v$ are integers. As $a$ and $c$ are odd, all the $r,\ldots,u$
must be odd. But then what about $b=rv+tu$?