# If a and b are odd integers then find the number of integral roots of $(x^{10} +ax^9 +b=0)$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> If a and b are odd integers then find the number of integral roots of $(x^{10} +ax^9 +b=0)$

---

I've no idea how to solve this question. Any help would be appreciated. :|

Comment: See the [Parity Root test.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/759950/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider the equation modulo $2$.

Comment: I've not yet studied Modular arithmetic. Any other method pls? :)

Comment: Or maybe you could just elaborate a bit. :)

Comment: You dont need modular arithmetic for that. Just check the parity of $x^{10}+ax^9+b$ if $a,b$ are odd. For example, consider the two cases, $x$ even or $x$ odd.

Comment: He means consider both cases when $x$ is odd and even, and see if there can be solution in either case.

Comment: He meant that you should consider what happens if *x* is odd, and what happens if *x* is even.

Answer (score 1):

O. Eqn with odd integers; where D (∆) = not a perfect sq.
Hence no intergral roots

Comment: I don't think that you have added much extra information to an old question.

Comment: @McCheng: On the contrary, this is a very good answer, unfortunately somewhat terse.