# Can the empty set be considered to have an even or odd number of elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here's the problem:

> Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and define a function $F: \mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathbb{Z}$ as follows: For all sets $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$,
>
> $$F(x) = \begin{cases} 
> 0 &\ \text{if $X$ has an even number of elements}\\
> 1 &\ \text{if $X$ has an odd number of elements}.
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Find $F(\emptyset)$.

So I'm hoping someone can help me determine whether nothing is itself an element, and, if not, whether the absence of an element is even or odd.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you know how many elements $\emptyset$ has?

Comment: Hint: Is zero an odd or an even number?

Comment: There are no elements in an empty set, by definition. However, I don't know whether nothing is even or odd...  can I say that nothing and 0 are the same thing?

Comment: Amy, there's nothing in the empty set, which means that there are $0$ elements. If $0$ were to be an element, then the set would have $1$ element.

Comment: @Amy: 'Nothing' is not a number so it does not make sense to say whether it is even or odd. I would advise against using the word to describe the empty set. As you have established, the empty set has zero elements, so to determine $F(\emptyset)$ you just need to determine whether $0$ is even or odd.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15556/is-zero-odd-or-even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero is an even number. It's $2 \times 0$.