# Are these subrings of $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Are the following subrings of $\Bbb Q$?

---

1) The set of non-negative rational numbers.

No since we don't have any additive inverses, and the subring should be armed with an Abelian group for addition.

---

2) The set of squares of rational numbers.

No since the squares of rational numbers are also all positive, and hence we don't have additive inverses.

---

3) The set of all rational numbers with odd numerators(when the fraction is completely reduced)

No since $\frac{3}{2} -\frac{1}{2}=\frac22$

---

Are these all correct reasonings. I would hate to misunderstand something seemingly so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1$ & $2$ are fine, but $\frac {2}{ 2} = \frac {1} {1}$ has odd numerator, when the fraction is completely reduced - so this isn't a counterexample. But $3-1$ is.

Comment: Oh yes, true! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Or for that matter $1-1$. (+1)

Comment: @Brian I hesitated to give $0$ as a counterexample (although this was my initial thought), because I didn't want to see one of [these](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15556/is-zero-odd-or-even) again ;-)

Comment: @Permute: Your item 3) talks of odd denominators but 'disproves' using even denominator example.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Odd numerators, yesterday I had odd denominators(and had trouble even seeing the difference in the two questions before three or four rereads

Comment: Oh! A blunder. Ignore my previous comment.