# How to denote an even number in mathematics?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I need a sign  for an even number (not $a\cdot 2$) in my formula. I tried to google it, but I saw only $2a$. Please tell me if there is a special sign?

Comment: An integer $n$ is even iff $n=2k$ for some natural number $k$.  That is, even numbers are characterized (or rather, defined) to be any number divisible by 2.  That's all there is to it.  No other signs, just divisibility by 2.

Comment: You can write $n\in 2\mathbb Z$ for "$n$ is an even integer".

Comment: how about $2 b$ ?  seriously, I don't think there is one. You could however follow the strategy of the top answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15556/is-zero-odd-or-even and make one up

Answer (score 8):

We often like to say that an even number is any $2k$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$.

But another way is to use $\mathbb Z$ with scalar multiplication.

I.e. $\mathbb Z = \{..., -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...\}$. You know. The integers.

So $2\mathbb Z = \{..., -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...\}$ because every element in $\mathbb Z$ gets multiplied by $2$. This is now the set of all even numbers.

Now, you can refer to a number $n$ as even if $n \in 2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

As denoted in the answer to this question: [Is zero odd or even?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15556/is-zero-odd-or-even), $N_e$ is used to denote even numbers and $N_o$ for odd numbers. However, you could use any notation as long as it's clear to the reader what you are trying to symbolize with it.