# Notation for every odd integer number

Tags: notation, integers

I have this equation:

> $$f(x)=\tan(x)$$

I found  the vertical asymptotes to be:

> $$x=\frac{\pi}{2}k$$

What is the proper notation for that k is equal to every odd number integer(negative,positive, and zero)?

$$k\in\mathbb{Z}$$ is for every integer, but is there such a symbol for every odd number integer?

Natural numbers are positive, and sometimes zero counting numbers, my question is about integers not natural numbers.

Comment: the vertical asymptotes are the zeros of the function $\cos(x)$

Comment: "the vertical asymptotes are the zeros of the function cos(x)"... which are $\pi/2(2k + 1)$... I don't at all see the point of this comment.

Comment: Sidenote; where writing math you don't have to use fancy symbols for everything. There is nothing wrong (and imo it should be encouraged) to use words instead wherever possible.

Comment: @Winther I was running out space on my AP Calculus Summer assignment, that is way all these questions are popping up.

Comment: You could simply write $k\rm~odd$, also

Comment: @Winther One of the most remarkable things in the history of mathematics is that we have stopped using words for everything. Having convenient notation is very important. Writing has its advantages (I prefer "for all" to $\forall$, for example), but, nevertheless, in my opinion we do need simple notation for the set of odd and even integers. $\mathbb{Z}_{2k + 1}$ is my proposal. Ahmed's idea is great as well.

Comment: @Mathematics The truth is there's a continuum between writing everything completely in symbolic logic and not even using a plus sign. Use standard notation all you like, no one will argue. Beyond that, if humans are reading it, it's better to err on the side of words.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{2k+1}$ is not a good choice since it might represent the group $\mathbb Z/(2k+1)\mathbb Z$.

Comment: And let's admit that we do not have a universal agreed notation on the set of odd integers. All the answers below are not clearer/shorter than the english one.

Comment: where come all this upvotes from??

Comment: @tired I came up with 7 different accounts, and got enough reputation to up vote myself clearly?  Good question idk where anybody wanna comment why they upvoted

Answer (score 16, accepted):

they are $$(2k+1)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$$ with $$k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Thanks that deserves to be a high school math hack.

Comment: @Sigma6RPU What's a "high school math hack"?

Comment: @JiK Anything that makes something complex, expressed in a simple elegant form.

Comment: @Sigma6RPU I would venture to say that *every serious mathematician in every field of mathematics* strives to express complex things in simple, elegant forms. That being the case, it does not seem very fitting to describe the natural, commonplace behavior of every mathematician as "[high school math hacking.]" I would have thought any hacking that a high school student would do would be associated with something *negative*. Like expressing something *simple* in a *complicated* way or something. But if it strikes you as positive, maybe you agree and it's just a difference in interpretation.

Answer (score 11):

You can go with $2\mathbb Z +1$

Comment: A good option. Relatedly  $2\mathbb Z $ for even and $ \mathbb{Z}\setminus 2\mathbb Z $ as alternative for odd.

Comment: @quid Isn't that quotient the set of integers mod 2?

Comment: @user3146 $\backslash \neq /$, but yes that notation is probably not ideal.

Comment: @Asinomás lol good point, I'm dumb

Comment: @user3146 so am I , I definitely see myself falling for that.

Comment: Easier still would be $x \epsilon 2\pi\Z $, without resorting to k, right?

Comment: think it would be $\pi \mathbb Z \setminus 2\pi \mathbb Z$

Comment: I can't get script z to work.  Sorry, I forgot it was odds

Answer (score 8):

As long as we're considering alternatives, you could always write
$$k\equiv 1\pmod 2$$

Answer (score 6):

Usually people write:

$$\frac{\pi}{2}(2k+1), k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Sometimes people would use  $\mathbb{O}$ for the set of all odd integers, but because it is not so standard they will tell you ahead of time:

$$\mathbb{O}=\{ 2n+1 : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

So then, after defining $\mathbb{O}$, you would say:

$$\frac{\pi}{2}k, k \in \mathbb{O}$$

Get used the $\in$, it simply means  "is a member of" some set.

Comment: Is that an "Oh" or a zero?

Comment: $0$ as the set of all numbers? That's not a good idea, I wouldn't like to write $0 \in 0$ anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @fleablood  I was wondering why it went bold.

Comment: Never seen this, but I like it.

Comment: Actually $\mathbb O$ is normally reserved for the octonian, as are $\mathbb H, \mathbb C, \mathbb R$.

Comment: Hmm good to know, I didn't know that @Jhon Ma, but I guess if you define it first for your purposes then we are good.  I've seen people use this before.

Comment: Yes, but $\mathbb O$ will be bugging me all the time I guess @@....

Comment: Don't worry, @Santiago $-$ you will never have to write $0\in \mathbb O$, because [$0$ is even](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/15556/1508)!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could write

$$x = \frac{\pi}{2}k \quad , \quad k = \pm1, \pm3, \pm5 \dots$$

Answer (score 1):

You could do $x \epsilon \pi \mathbb{Z} / 2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$, without resorting to $k$.