# Example Case of Product for Non-Existing Limits, Existing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I am a TA for a Calculus 1 class, and I got stumped on this question.  I remember there being example cases for this when I took an Analysis class, but I can't remember any.  Give an example where $$\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)*g(x))$$ exists but neither $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$$ nor $$\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$$ exists.

Comment: $f(x)=g(x)=1/x$

Comment: That doesn't work.  $\lim_{x\to 0}(1/x^2)=DNE$

Comment: $\lim \limits_{x \to 0 } 1/x^2 = \infty$

Comment: Notice that $f$ and $g$ must be bounded as $x \to 0$ - if $f$ were unbounded then $g$ would have to tend to $0$, which we don't want to be true.

Comment: A limit that diverges to infinity fails the technical definition of a limit, epsilon-delta definition.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/why-does-an-infinite-limit-not-exist

Comment: @MathematicsStudent there is a definition of convergence in which we can state that a function literally converges to infinity.  Whether $1/x$ or $1/|x|$ or $1/x^2$ have limits at zero can become a very semantic argument.  That being said, many calculus courses differentiate between $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = DNE$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = +\infty$; I suggest you verify with the professor whether these situations are supposed to be distinct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an extreme example that works simultaneously at all points, not just at $0$. Let

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x\text{ is irrational}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x\text{ is rational}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Neither has a limit at any point, but their product is the continuous constant function $0$.

Answer (score 3):

An example which might be easier for a Calc I student to understand:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x < 0\\
1 & x \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
and $g(x) = 1 - f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't require continuity use these
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{, if } x =1/n  \text{ for some natural n}\\ 
1 & \mbox{, otherwise}  \end{cases} 
$$

$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{, if } x =1/n  \text{ for some natural n}\\ 
0 & \mbox{, otherwise}  \end{cases} 
$$

as their product is zero everywhere.