# The limit of this function as x approaches 2 from the positive direction (the right).

Tags: calculus, limits

> ### $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 2}\frac {\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x-2}$$

Am I correct in thinking the limit does not exist? Since as x approaches 2 from the right the function increases to infinity and a limit cannot equal infinity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x-2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}\frac{\sqrt{(x-2)(x+2)}}{x-2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}\frac{\sqrt{(x-2)}\sqrt{(x+2)}}{x-2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}\frac{\sqrt{(x+2)}}{\sqrt{(x-2)}}$$

Then as you said the denominator tends to $0^+$ and hence the whole limit tends to $+\infty$

Comment: Does this mean the limit does not exist? Thanks!

Comment: @ConorJackson take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127691/607487, (spoiler: yes it does not exist since $\infty$ is a concept not an actual number). Feel free to upvote the  answer if it helped you.

Comment: Have tried however since I am a new user I won't appear publicly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! Good luck!