# I'm becoming iffy on using limits to describe vertical asymptotes, console my skepticism?

Tags: calculus, limits

I hear often in calculus classes that for a constant *a*, $\lim_{x \to 0} a/x = \infty$. But on closer inspection of this limit, I'm not so sure. Yes, of course dividing by zero is not defined. But if $\lim_{x \to 0} a/x = \infty$ does that also mean that

$\lim_{n \to \infty}$$\sum_{0}^n 0 = a$

While I have not taken real analysis, calculus is founded on using limits to describe the infinite. I suppose I'm a little bit shaken on what we are and are not allowed to talk about when describing vertically asymptotic behavior. Or perhaps, by the rules of limits, does $\lim_{n \to \infty}$$\sum_{0}^n 0 $ actually equal a constant?

Comment: $\sum_{0}^n 0 = 0$ for all $n$ so the limit is also $0$.

Comment: I am still confused as to how did you even arrive at the idea that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac a x$ diverges could imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n 0^i = a$?

Comment: "$\lim_{x \to 0} a/x = \infty$" is wrong. If you think you heard it in Calculus course, change class immediately (or pay more attention). If $a>0$, $\lim_{x \to 0^+} a/x = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} a/x = -\infty$, so $\lim_{x \to 0} a/x$ does not exist.

Comment: @Taladris I believe they are referring to the limit of the sequence $(\frac a x)_{n=1}^\infty$ and not of the function $f(x)=\frac a x$. And as far as I know, there is no notion of left or right limits of sequences.

Comment: @Seeker: I guess you mean $(\frac a n)_{n=1}^\infty$. I don't know. In that case, my comment "Pay more attention" is still valid...

Comment: @Taladris Yeah I meant to type $(\frac a n)_{n=1}^\infty$. And I agree that OP should  pay more attention to the topics being taught.

Comment: @Seeker You guys are all right. This was a stupid question. What I should have asked was "Is a sum of 0+0+0+0... and infinite number of times = 0, and can we prove it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from your last comment. Note that the infinite series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 0^i$ converges to a real number $L$ if the sequence formed by taking the partial sums of the series converges to to $L$. As pointed out in the comments, the partial sums of the infinite series $\sum_{i=1}^n0^i$ forms the sequence $a_n=(0^n)_{n=1}^\infty=0, 0, 0,\dots$ and we know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Thus, the infinite series $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 0^i=0 + 0 + 0+\cdots $$ converges to the real number $0$.

Answer (score 0):

As any standard text in calculus will tell you, a limit such as $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ expresses that, as $x$ gets closer to $a$, its function value $f(x)$ should also become correspondingly closer to the limit $L$. Overlooking the technical details of how that idea is made into a rigid, sensible proposition, that's all there is to it.

So what would $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=L$ or $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ mean? As above, they should mean that, as "$x$ gets *closer* to $\infty$, yada yada", or "yada yada, then $f(x)$ gets closer to $\infty$". But is any real number closer to $\infty$ than any other? No, by definition, they are all infinitely far from it, whether they are $1$ or $10^{10^{10^{10^{\ldots}}}}$.

In truth, whenever we use the symbol "$\infty$" in a formula involving a limit, we are committing an abuse of notation that conveniently conforms to what we would write for finite numbers. That is, limits in which $x$ or $f(x)$ are "approaching infinity" are not really getting "closer" to it but simply getting boundlessly larger. They are not *con*-verging to a number but *di*-verging away. Your formula $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{a}{x}=``\infty"$ (which we may otherwise just write as "does not exist") $^{(1)}$ simply means that the expression in the limit gets boundlessly larger as $x$ is brought to $0$ (from the positive side). See [MSE Q127689](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127689).

Infinity is not a number in the conventional sense. You could (perfectly legitimately) bend the rules of your mathematical theory to allow infinity to be considered a number (as in the *extended reals*), but in so doing, identities as fundamental as $a-a=0$ no longer necessarily true, and you therefore incur limitations on the arithmetic operations you are able to carry out. See [MSE Q60766](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766). Explicitly, the extended real numbers are not a *field*. The standard workaround to this is to simply prohibit $\infty$ from being used as a number in the theory, in much the same way as we prohibit division by zero. That is, we work strictly in the *real numbers* (read, *finite* numbers). So, your implied paradoxical proof of

$$\begin{align}\frac{a}{0}\,&``="\,\infty
\\&``="\,\left(1+1+\ldots+1\right)
\\a\,&``="\,\left(0+0+\ldots+0\right)
\end{align}$$

simply would not hold because we prohibit treating $\infty$ as an ordinary number (and also prohibit division by zero) for the very purpose of avoiding contradictions like this. See [MSE Q36289](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36289). Your argument was also flawed in that limits cannot be so casually rearranged, and $\lim \frac{a}{b}=\lim c$ does *not* necessarily imply $\lim a=\lim c\cdot b$. Explicitly, you cannot generally rearrange terms *out* of the limit operator.

In the case of your sum of zeros, this is essentially to Zeno's paradox, which has a great body of work devoted to it. A good place to start studying would be [SEP: Zeno’s Paradoxes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-zeno/). The bottom line is that we would evaluate any sum of zeros as zero, $\displaystyle \sum 0 = 0$, whether it has finitely many of them or infinitely many. In order to sum a set of terms to a nonzero constant (as in an integral), the terms must be (mostly) nonzero.

$^{(1)}$ You ought to have written $0^+$ in your formula since you are strictly approaching $0$ from the positive side; $0^-$ would have given you $-\infty$.