# Can someone help me solve this limits question?

Tags: limits, infinity

$$\begin{align}\lim x → ∞\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
f(x) = {\frac{2^{x+1}+{3^{x+1}}}{2^x + 3^x}} \\
\end{align}$$

I tried using L Hopitable but that gives the same expression. Also tried using substitution but I didn't get anywhere. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it would be good to see an argument based on general big-$O$ principles, but I'm not remembering details well enough to write one right now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To begin with
$$f(x)=\frac{2\cdot(\frac23)^x+3}{(\frac23)^x+1}$$
it follows that
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=3.$$
However
$$f(x)=\frac{2+3\cdot(\frac32)^x}{1+(\frac32)^x}$$
in such a case, we get that
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=2.$$

Comment: I think you have a serious mistake in evaluating the limit the second time. Check it ( the limit is *only* when $\;x\to \infty\;$ . That $\;-\infty\;$ has no business there)

Comment: $x\to\infty$ means $|x|\to+\infty$

Comment: If $x\to\infty$ means $x\to+\infty$, you are right

Comment: Why divide by 3^x for +∞ and 2^x for -∞? I don't get that. Also, what is the thinking process behind this? I for example wouldn't know you would have to divide in this case..

Comment: It is the second one, @ziangchen...it always has been. In complex analysis it can be as the first option, and even then it usually is defined and agreed upon.

Comment: @ace , it is done so because then in each case you get fractions that when taking the limit become less than one and thus converge to zero: $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\frac32\right)^x=0$$

Comment: I see now. Thanks for the explanation. This solution looks the most simplest to me.

Comment: @ace This is not a solution. The limit DOES exist.

Comment: @J.W.Perry If $x\to\infty$ means $x\to+\infty$, you are right: The limit DOES exist!

Comment: @ziangchen In what world or language has $x \rightarrow \infty$ ever meant anything other than positive infinity?

Comment: @ziangchen take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371905/which-infinity-is-meant-in-limits?rq=1).

Comment: @ziangchen The answer in that post is precisely the same infinity, and definition of limit, that I learned about in school, and it is a nice post. No hard feelings my friend, I wish you only well and thank you for your fine work.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy,@J.W.Perry Oh, frequently, $\infty$ means $+\infty$.  In that post, $(a,\infty)$, $\infty$ means $+\infty$. But, For example, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac1x)^x=e$, here $x\to\infty$ means $|x|\to+\infty$. See Zorch's "Mathematical analysis I", Chapter 3.2

Comment: Sometimes, $x\to\infty$ means $x\to+\infty$; Sometimes, $x\to\infty$ means $|x|\to+\infty$

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea. Try writing,
\begin{align*}
\frac{2^{x+1}+3^{x+1}}{2^x+3^x} &= \frac{2 \cdot 2^x+3 \cdot 3^x}{2^x+3^x} \\
&=\frac{3\cdot 2^x - 2^x+3 \cdot 3^x}{2^x+3^x} \\
&=\frac{3\left( 2^x+3^x \right)-2^x}{2^x+3^x} \\
&=3-\frac{2^x}{2^x+3^x} \\
&=3-\frac{\frac{2^x}{2^x}}{\frac{2^x}{2^x}+\frac{3^x}{2^x}} \\
&=3-\frac{1}{1+\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^x}.
\end{align*}
Now most people would just look at this and say
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 3-\frac{1}{1+\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^x} \right)=3.$$

Comment: What "more rigour" is needed there? It is simply arithmetic of limits.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For the formal argument, it is useful to divide top and bottom by $3^x$. Before doing that, it is a good idea to think about the numbers, and decide what the limit will be.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the numerator and the denominator by $3^{x+1}$.