# limit of $\frac{x^x -1}{x}$ as x tends to zero

Tags: limits, exponentiation

I was wondering if i could get any help with the following:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{x^x -1}{x} $$.

thank you.

My attempt:

$$ \lim = \frac{e^{x \ln(x)} - 1}{x} = \lim ( x \ln (x)( x \ln(x) + 1)) $$

Comment: Your $\frac{x\ln x-1}{x}$ should have been $\frac{e^{x\ln x}-1}{x}$.  And your differentiation of $x\ln x$ was not correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you

Comment: You are welcome.  The basic L'Hospital's Rule strategy was fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use L'Hopital's rule to get:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} x^x(\ln x+1)=\lim_{x \to 0}x^x \ln x-\lim_{x \to 0} x^x=(\lim_{x \to 0} x^x \ln x) -1=((\lim_{x \to 0} x^x)(\lim_{x \to 0} \ln x))-1=(1)(-\infty)-1=-\infty$$

The limit does not exist.

Comment: Why does it not exist? How would you show one side goes to something else.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Because $-\infty$ wouldn't be a limit per se.

Comment: I thought DNE was only used to show that the RH limit does not agree with the LH limit.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Not necessarily.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/why-does-a-limit-at-infinity-not-exist and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203/infinite-limits

Answer (score 4):

We may also avoid De L'Hospital theorem. Since
$$ \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to 0^+} x\log(x)=0,$$
we have:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^{x\log x}-1}{x\log x}\cdot\log(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\log(x) = -\infty.$$

Comment: Nice. Does it make a difference to use ln or log in this case?

Comment: @gnp: no, it doesn't. For my standards, $\log$ means the natural logarithm as well as $\ln$.

Answer (score 0):

Use an *asymptotic expansion:*

$x^x=\mathrm e^{x\ln x}=1+x\ln x+o(x\ln x)$, hence
$$\frac{x^x-1}x=\frac{x\ln x+o(x\ln x)}x=\ln x+o(\ln x)\sim\ln x\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{}-\infty.$$